# Bitcoin-cli sendtoaddress error Fallbackfee is disabled. Wait a few blocks or enable -fallbackfee

Tags: error

I am following the documentation to perform transactions when I put the command:
bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress "xx address" 1.0
return:

```
Fee estimation failed. Fallbackfee is disabled. Wait a few blocks or enable -fallbackfee.
```

In my bitcoin.conf I enable this option in fallbackfee = true or enabled but nothing happed

this is my mempoolinfo:

```
{
  "loaded": true,
  "size": 0,
  "bytes": 0,
  "usage": 0,
  "maxmempool": 300000000,
  "mempoolminfee": 0.00001000,
  "minrelaytxfee": 0.00001000
}
```

I have read the other posts but I still don't have the solution, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fallbackfee` takes a fee rate as a parameter, not a boolean. The fee rate is denominated in BTC/kvB. For a 1 sat/byte fee rate, you would do `fallbackfee=0.00001`.

Comment: thnx very much :) (Y)